# Is it possible to share the same message queue between two threads?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi

What I would like to do is to have one thread waiting for messages (`WaitMessage`) and another processing the logic of the application. The first thread would wake up on every message, signal somehow this event to the other thread, go to sleep again, etc. Is this possible?

**UPDATE**

Consider the following situation. We have a GUI thread, and this thread is busy in a long calculation. If there is no other thread, there is no option but to check for new messages from time to time. Otherwise, the GUI would become irresponsive during the long calculation. Right now my system uses this "polling" approach (it has a single thread that checks the message queue from time to time.) However, I would like to know whether this other solution is possible: Have another thread waiting on the OS message queue of the GUI so that when a Windows message arrives this thread will wake up and tell the other about the message. Note that I'm not asking how to communicate the news between threads but whether it is possible for the second thread to wait for OS messages that arrive in the queue of the first thread.

I should also add that I cannot have two different threads, one for the GUI and another for the calculations, because the system I'm working on is a Virtual Machine on top of which runs a Smalltalk image that is not thread safe. That's why having a thread that only signals new OS messages would be the ideal solution (if possible.)

Comment: What would be the point of that? That can only make your program more complex and slower. It can't bring any benefits.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The short answer would be: to make sure the app is responsive even if it is busy with some long calculation; plus I would prefer to avoid pulling events. Why do you think the waiting thread would slow down the execution?

Comment: Don't send the messages to the GUI thread

Comment: Would like to know what is the problem with what I offered. Maybe we will come up with other solution.

Comment: So, have the GUI thread deal with GUI messages, and have the other messages go directly to the other thread.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Unfortunately this is not an option in my case (see the last paragraph of the UPDATE.) Should I conclude from your comments that the "solution" I prefer is impossible?

Comment: That's a really bad solution to your problem. It would be far better to find a proper solution than to do this.

Comment: You really need to move your long calculations to a different thread, they don't belong in the GUI thread to begin with. Let the GUI thread manage the GUI and service messages, do any long-running things in another thread.  If you can't do that because your library is not thread safe, then you have 4 options - 1) find a thread safe library, 2) have the calculations poll the message queue periodically, 3) break up the calculations into small chunks that can be triggered by posting messages to yourself, or 4) move the library to a separate process that communicates with your main app.

Comment: It is not possible for one thread to wait on, and service, another thread's message queue.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Many thanks. Your comment above is the piece of information for which I needed explicit confirmation/rejection. In my case solution 2) from your list is the one I'm using, but at least I now know that the alternative I had in mind is inviable. Could you move your last comment to your answer below so I can click on the checkmark?

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia: done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on what the second thread needs to do once the first thread has received a message.

If the second thread simply needs to know the first thread received a message, the first thread could signal an [Event object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682655.aspx) using [`SetEvent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686211.aspx) or [`PulseEvent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684914.aspx), and the second thread could wait on that event using [`WaitForSingleObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032.aspx).

If the second thread needs data from the first thread, it could use an [I/O Completion Port](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198.aspx). The first thread could wrap the data inside a dynamically allocated struct and post it to the port using [`PostQueuedCompletionStatus()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365458.aspx), and the second thread could wait for the data using [`GetQueuedCompletionStatus()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364986.aspx) and then free it when done using it.

**Update**: based on new information you have provided, it is not possible for one thread to wait on or service another thread's message queue.  Only the thread that created and owns the queue can poll messages from its queue.  Each thread has its own message queue.

You really need to move your long calculations to a different thread, they don't belong in the GUI thread to begin with. Let the GUI thread manage the GUI and service messages, do any long-running things in another thread.

If you can't do that because your chosen library is not thread safe, then you have 4 options:

1. find a different library that is thread safe.
2. have the calculations poll the message queue periodically when running in the GUI thread.
3. break up the calculations into small chunks that can be triggered by the GUI thread posting messages to itself.  Post a message and return to the message loop.  When the message is received, do a little bit of work, post the next message, and return to the message loop.  Repeat as needed until the work is done.  This allows the GUI thread to continue servicing the message queue in between each calculation step.
4. move the library to a separate process that communicates back with your main app as needed.

Comment: Thanks Remy. Unfortunately the second thread is busy with a long calculation and because of that cannot `Wait`. The only it can do it to check frequently enough whether the first thread changed a global flag indicating that there are new messages in the queue.

Comment: So what is wrong with that? The second thread will handle the flag when safe for it to do so, when it decides to take a break from what it is currently doing to do something else.  That is perfectly fine solution, based on your descriptions. The calculations belong in a separate thread not in the GUI thread.

Comment: "it is not possible for one thread to wait on or service another thread's message queue"  Isn't that exactly what AttachThreadInput does?  (I'm not saying it's a good idea.  I'm just trying to understand that assertion.  The best course is to do the long calculation on a non-GUI thread, as you propose.)

Comment: No, that is not what `AttachThreadInput()` does.  It allows two threads to share the same **input queue** (for handling things like keyboard focus, etc), not the same **message queue**.  There is a difference. And Raymond Chen's blog has several postings on the dangers of (mis)using `AttachThreadInput()`.